# Can a function take both IntoIterator<T> and IntoIterator<&T>?

Tags: rust

I want a function that takes two arguments, both of which can be turned into an iterator of `Foo`. The snag is that I'd like to accept things which are both `IntoIterator<Foo>` and also `IntoIterator<&Foo>`. Importantly `Foo` is `Copy` so I can cheaply create an owned copy from it's reference.

The solution I currently have is:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::iter::IntoIterator;

fn main() {
    let foos = [Foo {}, Foo {}, Foo {}];
    let references = || foos.iter();
    let owned = || foos.iter().cloned();
    bar(references(), references());
    bar(references(), owned());
    bar(owned(), references());
    bar(owned(), owned());
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Foo {
    // code ommitted here
}

impl<'a> From<Foo> for Cow<'a, Foo> {
    fn from(foo: Foo) -> Self {
        Self::Owned(foo)
    }
}

impl<'a> From<&'a Foo> for Cow<'a, Foo> {
    fn from(foo: &'a Foo) -> Self {
        Self::Borrowed(foo)
    }
}

fn bar<'a, AIter, A, BIter, B>(alpha_iter: AIter, beta_iter: BIter)
  where 
    AIter: IntoIterator<Item=A>,
    A: Into<Cow<'a, Foo>>,
    BIter: IntoIterator<Item=B>,
    B: Into<Cow<'a, Foo>>
{
    for (alpha, beta) in alpha_iter.into_iter().zip(beta_iter.into_iter()) {
       some_foo_specific_thing(*alpha.into(), *beta.into());
    }
}

fn some_foo_specific_thing(alpha: Foo, beta: Foo) {
    // code ommitted here
}
```

<sup>[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d19729789bf114eb73236046b5eacbef)</sup>

Is there a way to do this in less lines / without `Cow`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you don't need exactly `IntoIterator` bound here. It's just enough for `Iterator<Item = Foo>`.

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::iter::IntoIterator;

fn main() {
    let foos = [Foo {}, Foo {}, Foo {}];
    let references = || foos.iter(); // it is iterator itself
    let owned = || foos.iter().cloned(); // it is iterator itself
    bar(references(), references());
    bar(references(), owned());
    bar(owned(), references());
    bar(owned(), owned());
}
```

```rust
fn bar<'a, AIter, A, BIter, B>(alpha_iter: AIter, beta_iter: BIter)
  where 
    AIter: Iterator<Item = A>,
    A: Into<Cow<'a, Foo>>,
    BIter: Iterator<Item = B>,
    B: Into<Cow<'a, Foo>>
{
    for (alpha, beta) in alpha_iter.zip(beta_iter) {
       some_foo_specific_thing(*alpha.into(), *beta.into());
    }
}
```

Secondly, I think it is better to use [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) trait:

```
fn bar<'a, AIter, A, BIter, B>(alpha_iter: AIter, beta_iter: BIter)
  where 
    AIter: Iterator<Item = A>,
    A: std::borrow::Borrow<Foo> + Copy,
    BIter: Iterator<Item = B>,
    B: std::borrow::Borrow<Foo> + Copy,
{
    let alpha_iter = alpha_iter.map(|item| *item.borrow()); // here we  get a reference to an item and then make a copy to own it
    let beta_iter = beta_iter.map(|item| *item.borrow()); // here we  get a reference to an item and then make a copy to own it
    
    for (alpha, beta) in alpha_iter.zip(beta_iter) {
       some_foo_specific_thing(alpha, beta);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is in the vast majority of cases no reason to recommend `Iterator` over `IntoIterator`. `IntoIterator` is the more general, preferable bound because it is automatically implemented for all iterators as well as for iterables. Moreover, the version using `Into` does not compile.

Comment: Also my bad for a minimal test case that didn't cover it, but I am using it for other things that aren't iterators (e.g. slice references)

Comment: However: bingo! I knew there was a trait I was missing, and `Borrow` is the answer! Many thanks @Dmitry :D